# Get selected checkboxes values from table and pass those values into ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get selected checkbox values from table and pass those values into ajax.Below code I need to pass selected_Device_Mac into ajax. Using inner text i am to get single mac values.i want to check multiple checkboxes and pass each mac values into ajax.How to implement this?

```
function getDeviceType() {

  var selected_Device_Mac = '';

   var selected_device_id = '';


   ($('#query-type').val() === 'single'){
    if ($('#PA').is(":visible")) {

       console.log("before")
       selected_Device_Mac = document.getElementById("macaddr1").innerText;
       selected_device_id = '#Selected_Device';

       console.log("after")

   } else if ($('#MP').is(":visible")) {
       selected_Device_Mac = document.getElementById("macaddr2").value;
       selected_device_id = '#Selected_Snmp_Device';
   }

  }
   $('#cover-spin').show();


  $.ajax({

       method: "GET",
       dataType: "text",
       url: "getDeviceType",
       data: {
           mac : selected_Device_Mac,
       },
```

Answer (score 1):

ur code is not clean so that im not sure this is what you need
this code is the way to get value of multi checkbox

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Title Page</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="checkbox" value="a">a
  <input type="checkbox" value="b">b
  <input type="checkbox" value="c">c
  <input type="checkbox" value="d">d
  <input type="checkbox" value="e">e
  <button onclick="test()" class="btn btn-default">click</button>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
  var test = ()=>{
   let check_list=[];
   $('body').find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
                   check_list.push($(this).val());
                });
   alert(check_list);
  }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks.Same thing i am trying              var selectedMac = new Array();

         $('input[name="checkBox_mac"]:checked').each(function() {
          selectedMac.push(this.value);
         });
alert("Number of selected mac: "+selectedMac.length+"\n"+"And, they are: "+selectedMac);

Comment: It is taking mac value if i checked 2 checkboxes.But selectedMac coming as null.

Comment: can u write more detail ??

Comment: yes.Below the code i am getting single mac address from table.

Comment: var macaddr = document.getElementById("macAdd").innerText;
            mac = macaddr.replace(/\\/g, "").split(',');

Comment: how to iterate mac here if i checked multiple checkboxes in table.